# localectlで変更した設定が反映されない

Tags: linux, centos

初めて仮想OS、およびLinuxを扱う者です。CentOS7について質問があります。

次のようなコマンドで、[ここ](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)から、CentOS 7.0 x64 (2016/4/14現在、上から3つ目)をBoxとして入手し、Vagrantでinit, upして仮想OSを立ち上げました。

```
vagrant box add centos7 https://github.com/tommy-muehle/puppet-vagrant-boxes/releases/download/1.1.0/centos-7.0-x86_64.box
vagrant init centos7
vagrant up
```

TeraTermでこの仮想OSに接続し、シェルからの入力が可能になりました。

その際、シェルに表示される内容がドイツ語になっていたため、下記リンクの内容に従い、ロケールの設定を行いました。

> [CentOS]CentOS7でのロケール(locale)の確認及び変更
> http://zero-config.com/centos/changelocale-002.html

設定を確認すると、次のようになりました。

> [vagrant@localhost opt]$ localectl status
> System Locale: LANG=ja.JP.eucjp
> VC Keymap: de
> X11 Layout: de
> X11 Model: pc105
> X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

しかし、例えばコマンドを打ち間違えたりした場合の警告文は、下記のようにドイツ語のままでした。

> [vagrant@localhost opt]$ la
> -bash: la: Kommando nicht gefunden.

keymapをusに変更しても同様でした。
これは仕様でしょうか？それとも変更可能なのでしょうか？

OSやシェルの仕組みに関連するかと思われるので、補足としてその内容が分かる文書などを教えていただければ幸いです。

## 追記

参考までに...
locale の実行結果

> [vagrant@localhost ~]$ locale locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default
> locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to
> default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to
> default locale: No such file or directory LANG=ja.JP.eucjp
> LC_CTYPE="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_NUMERIC="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_TIME="ja.JP.eucjp"
> LC_COLLATE="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_MONETARY="ja.JP.eucjp"
> LC_MESSAGES="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_PAPER="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_NAME="ja.JP.eucjp"
> LC_ADDRESS="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_TELEPHONE="ja.JP.eucjp"
> LC_MEASUREMENT="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja.JP.eucjp" LC_ALL=

locale -a の実行結果(長すぎるので、一部のみ)

> [vagrant@localhost ~]$ locale -a locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
> default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
> LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
> Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory C
> POSIX aa_DJ aa_DJ.iso88591

Comment: `locale` と `locale -a` の出力はどうなりますか？ あと最近はutf-8が一般的になっていると思いますがeucでOKですか？（駄目なわけでは無いです。確認です。）

Comment: その記事の末尾にも書かれているように `localectl` で設定してもその場で反映されるわけではありませんが、再ログインや `source /etc/locale.conf` は試されましたか？

Comment: 記事末尾を確認していませんでした。。

再起動によって設定変更の反映を確認しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

`localectl`で設定してもその場で反映されるわけではありません。
再ログインや`source /etc/locale.conf`が必要です。